# New computer won't post with more than 1 stick of RAM, 3 out of 4 sticks bad or psu/mobo issue?

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, power-supply

I'm having a perplexing problem and wondered if someone might help because it seems highly unlikely that I have a 75% failure rate from the four sticks of RAM I purchased new, but that seems to be the case.

```
Components:
Motherboard Asus B550-Creator
Processor: AMD 5950x
Memory: Kingston Fury 32GBx4 DDR4-3600
Graphics Card: MSI RTX 3070
PSU: Super Flower Leadex Platinum 850w
```

I can only get the computer to boot with one stick of RAM. 2 or 4 modules in any combination result in a yellow DRAM LED to hang with no video output or post.

I can get to the BIOS with one module, though only with two of the four sticks. The other two result in the same yellow light. I'm using socket B2 as specified by the manual for all tests of a single stick of RAM. Now of the two modules that I have gotten to work, one cycles through each of the LED's on the motherboard (yellow DRAM, red CPU, white VGA) before finally going to the green light and booting. The other stick, however, the computer seems like it goes through a couple, then loses power and has to restart (fans start to spin down, the light sequence starts over) before it posts and displays an image on the screen. This consistently happens every time.

I flashed the bios to the newest firmware and enabled DOCP, but neither had an effect.

I have now tried two brands of RAM and both behave similarly. I also removed the CPU to ensure there were no bent pins and there were none. Is there anything else to try before I RMA the motherboard?

Also, while I'm at it, is there any reason my keyboard and mouse would not work when plugged-in? The screen at startup says one keyboard one mouse, but none of the keys work unless I move my Razer keyboard off of the USB ports next to the PS2 port and onto one of the other ones.

Comment: DDR4 issues are rarely if ever caused by a PSU issue.  What is more likely is the memory itself isn't compatible with the processor and the single module configuration working is a fluke.  "is there any reason that my keyboard and mouse would not work when plugged in?" - There is normally an option within the firmware settings to allow USB legacy devices within the UEFI shell.  If you have tested each individual memory module, by itself to rule out the other 3 modules are actually bad, that honestly is the type of behavior I would expect when there is a bend pin in a LGA socket.

Comment: @Ramhound In single memory configuration only 1 of 4 memory sticks works as a single module, and 1 sort of works with a weird power flicker  The other two do not work as a single module at all.  I would simply blame the memory, but it seemed really really unlikely that I'd have 3 bad memory sticks out of a pack of 4.   I can certainly remove the processor and see if a pin could be off.  The memory should be compatible as kingston has always been on AMD's lists.  They sold their hyper X brand to HP, but these should be functionally the same just rebranded.

Comment: Ryzen has always been very particular about memory compatibility.  I assume this memory was purchased from a large box supplier.

Comment: This does sound like a compatibility issue, but I'm speculating.

Comment: @ramhound I tested with a different memory brand, same problem.  Removed processor to check pins, no issues. I guess faulty motherboard is about all I have left?

Comment: @stainlesssteelrat I’ve now tried two different brands of ram with the same results. Seems like the motherboard may be at fault

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a faulty motherboard. Once that was replaced everything worked.